# Her microphone produces white noise, after a while?

Tags: troubleshooting, microphone, video-chat

When my friend Skypes with me or gets on FB Video with me, her sound works fine... at first.  After a bit, it starts sounding like loud static.  It happens more frequently as we restart video chats, until it happens as soon as we open video chats.  We usually restart her PC to fix the issue.  Is there a process we could kill, maybe?

Skip that question, if you will, and jump to these two: How do we fix this?  Why is this happening?

Comment: It could be electrical interference. What kind of microphone does your friend have?

Comment: It's a webcam mic, mounted on a laptop.